# How to get the complete list of followers

Tags: c#, api, twitter, tweetsharp

Using the last version of the [tweetsharp library](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp) for the twitter api, i am trying to get all the followers for a specific user. But i can only get the last 100 followers with this method:

```
IEnumerable<TwitterUser> f_followers = service.ListFollowersOf(user_id);
```

This method has a second parameter which is "long cursor", but i don't know how to use it.
I tried to use it as an offset but it does not work.
I presume that after each request, i need a cursorNext that i can use for the next request.

```
IEnumerable<TwitterUser> f_followers = service.ListFollowersOf(user_id, cursorNext);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Based on the tweetsharp code it looks like the overload that takes the `long cursor` is intended to be used for paging. If your goal is to get a complete list of followers then this probably isn't the method you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know tweetsharp at all, but based on the [following link](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp/blob/master/src/net40/TweetSharp.Next.Tests/Service/TwitterServiceTests.cs) you could try the following:

```
var followers = service.ListFollowersOf(user_id);
while (followers.NextCursor != null)
{
    followers =  service.ListFollowersOf(user_id, followers.NextCursor);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! it works but i have to request first `var followers = service.ListFollowersOf(user_id,-1);` otherwise NextCursor will always be null. Thanks a lot!!