# Getting complete list of followers from twitter with c#

Tags: asp.net, twitter

i want to get complete list of followers using REST API with c# but i only get 20 followers

```
var postBody = "screen_name=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(screen_name);//
resource_url += "?" + postBody;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string result = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
JObject j = JObject.Parse(result);
JArray data = (JArray)j["users"];
```

So with the above codes, i get only 20 followers and from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743551/how-to-get-the-complete-list-of-followers) i see in an answer there is a broken link to a package. Also, i am using only Newton.Json. How do i get complete list of followers?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add parameters to your query with the `cursor` provided in the json returned in your first query.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids

Comment: Hi, i tried using this. actually i am trying to pass screen_name through a text box and a button event and if i pass the queries it looks like https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=?&count=5000?screen_name=billingparadise but you know it isn't correct. How do i get it to the right format?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I do understand what your problem is. But getting all the followers of a member is not a 'simple' process.

I would suggest that you try out the project Tweetinvi and learn more about this feature here : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Get-All-Followers-Code.

You will first want to get all the users ids and then get the user objects via.

Then you can use `var userIds = User.GetUsersFromIds(userIds);` to get the users from Followers.

**NOTE** : Remember that Twitter has rate limits on its API. Take a look at https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Rate-Limits to learn how to use them.

For simplicity I would suggest that you use :

`RateLimit.RateLimitTrackerMode = RateLimitTrackerMode.TrackAndAwait;`

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.I have checked your library earlier.Actually want to get screen names with images.Does Tweetinvi help me for this?

Comment: Yes, when you get the user `User.GetUsersFromIds(userIds);` you will get all the information you need to.